# What are the optimal setups for planetary interaction?

Tags: eve-online

I recently moved in null sec and I was wondering about the optimal setup for an excavation colony.

Currently, I have all the PI skills at IV and I want to setup a colony that produces P2 items.

With these prerequisites ( and, if you want, with all skills at V ): **What is the optimal setup for planetary interaction?**

**Bonus:** Any image will be greatly welcome and surely help everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, turns out that a really good way to manage power grid is to stretch the whole colony into a big line.

This way you save power grid necessary to put extractors close to hot spots, with the addition that you have a lot more room to move extractor heads (since the extractor itself is near the hotspot).

[image: PI Scheme]

I'll accept this answer in few days if nobody else answers.

Source:https://www.reddit.com/r/Eve/comments/5v6v8i/simple_p2_pi_setup_help/